# Calculating volume of buildings using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-2

I am working with QGIS 2 or 3

I have DSM and DTM already so I can calculate DSM - DTM:

[image]

Plus, I have shapefile with buildings' footprints.

How to calculate volume of every single building using DSM-DTM layer and add this value in m^3 to feature table? (Like with Zonal stats?)

Comment: If you are confident that DSM > DTM is met, then simply `(pixel size)^2 * (DSM - DTM)` will give you the answer. Then you can use Zonal Statistics tool on the output, too.

Comment: So if I can estimate, that LIDAR gives 0.5m grid, can I just type in raster calculator (0.5 * 0.5) * (DSM-DTM)? Won't it give me a wrong volume? By the way, these pixels are 2m, 1m or 0.5m, depends on the situation, cause DSM and DTM is a merge of best possible data.

Comment: Yep, apart from how you process LiDAR to produce the grid. By the way, what software do you use for processing LiDAR, may I ask?

Comment: Never mind. Just thought it would help to find the level of confidence about the DSM-DTM relationship. Somewhere in the process to rasterize the point cloud you will face uncertainty in accuracy of z-value. That's all.

Comment: Everything is in QGIS, first, after downloading .asc files with LiDAR data, I run algorithm to choose the best possible resolution (when there is no data with 0.5m resolution it merges .asc parts with lower resolution). Then basing on that I get rid of everything that is outside of footprints to lower amount of data needed. Now I can calculate perimeter, height and other parameters of buildings. Another question is how to do 3D model of buildings to display in threejs or something like that? I mean, a real 3D model, not just footprint + height which gives me cubes only (Qgis2threejs).

Comment: As far as I can see your approach is robust and productive at the same time. However, if your ultimate goal is viewing it in 3D space, why don't you use point-cloud oriented software? I highly recommend [Cloud Compare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/) which can calculate volume and allow you 3D view, and easy handling of ASCII inputs.

Answer (score 1):

### Proposal for a more robust approach

A more robust approach would probably entail:

1. Using the building footprint shapefile, calculate *median* height of DSM inside each feature. This will represent the absolute height of each building.
2. Using the building footprint shapefile, calculate *median* height of DTM inside each feature. This will be the absolute height of the terrain under each building.
3. Compute the difference of the two, DSM-DTM. This is the relative height of each building.
4. Compute the volume multiplying the area of each feature (i.e. the footprint of each building) by its relative height.

[image: LAS median]

### Notes

- Use the *median*, not the *average* of pixel values in order to exclude the contributions of erroneous pixels/points. You don't want to bring into the average the height of chimneys not the values of point which are at ground level, but happen to be included in an abundant footprint.
- If you can, calculate the median values directly from the imported `*.asc` files (i.e. as vector points, not interpolated raster). Interpolation by definition brings in an additional uncertainty.
- This is a pretty simple/simplistic approach, which assumes flat roofs, as per your original request. If you are into more precise calculations, there are specialized software to do that which take into account the gutter, the full of the roof, different root flaps, chimneys, false roof points, etc.

Comment: Just not sure, I did it, but what about properties that are not regular at all in shape, have very sloped roofs and/or one part very tall and the rest one storey improvement? Info about these irregularities is available in LiDAR files, but will these medians deal with that as well?

Comment: I second @Vilq given the original data is LiDAR and the subject is the building (i.e. high aspect), approximated calculation using the already gridded raster is too simplistic, and I do not feel it is useful for further analysis. *(Maybe I am wrong...)*.